# Need help writing a query to pull a substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to pull data from a string -

`'./Iowa/Hospital/Main Campus/Maternal Child/PEDS/RN'`.

I"m using SQL Developer on an Oracle DB. I need to pull `'Main Campus'` from the string and I'm having trouble with the query.  This is what I've tried, but I get `'Main Campus/Maternal C'`:

```sql
select
    substr(
        primaryorgpathnm, instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,3) + 1, 
        length(primaryorgpathnm) - instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',-1,3))
from
    vp_primaryorg
```

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By counting the slashes from the beginning everywhere, we can write

```sql
select
    substr(
        primaryorgpathnm,
        instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,3) + 1, 
        instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,4) - instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,3) - 1
    ) as result
from
    vp_primaryorg
```

The third argument to `substr` calculates the length of the string between the 3rd and 4th `/`.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f040d/4/0

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired result:

```
select
       regexp_substr(primaryorgpathnm, '[^/]+', 1, 4) as primaryorgpathnm
from 
       vp_primaryorg
```

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Result:

```
primaryorgpathnm
================
Main Campus
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract based on the length of the element of the string then you need to count the number of characters between the two enclosing slashes - not base it on the overall length of the string:

```
select
    substr(
        primaryorgpathnm, instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,3) + 1, 
        instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,4) - instr(primaryorgpathnm,'/',1,3) - 1)
from
    vp_primaryorg
```

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
select
    regexp_substr(
        primaryorgpathnm, '(.*?)(/|$)', 1, 4, null, 1
    )
from
    vp_primaryorg
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8546c915de127eefc71d231d790b675b)